# Ratios of boys and girls via reciprocal of geometric distribution

Tags: probability, geometric-distribution

Given the setting:

> In a world where everyone wants a girl child, each family continues having babies till they have a girl. What do you think will the boy to girl ratio be eventually? (Assuming probability of having a boy or a girl is the same).

Is the following reasoning correct: the ratio of females in each family should be $\text{Exp}(\frac{1}{X}) =1-\ln(2)$ where $X\sim \text{Geo}(\frac{1}{2})$ since there is only one girl per family and variable amount of boys.

How can it be reconciled with the correct answer of a total uniform gender population ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectation of $\frac1X$ (with $X\ge1$) is not suitable for this problem. $\frac1X$ represents the number of *total children* born per *boy* and takes fractional values, whereas what you really want is the number of *boys* born per *girl*, for which taking $E(X-1)=1$ suffices.

If you tried using $\frac1{X-1}$ to account for the final girl, you would divide by zero upon setting $X=1$.

Comment: I understand and agree, but if we take X as geometric random variable that represents the amount of children a family has (with parameter 1/2) since I know each family has only one girl, wouldn't $\frac{1}{X}$ represent the ratio of girls in the family?

Comment: @Mattiatore You cannot add ratios directly. You would have to use a more complicated formula, and here the complication can be sidestepped by calculating on a more appropriate variable (see edit).

Comment: I see, so to use this method I would need to derive a new pdf for that r.v.

Comment: @Mattiatore Certainly.